# Getting error while deleting recyclerview items

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I know it's a very old question but even after referring a lot of solutions nothing could solve my issue . Actually I'm trying to remove items of recyclerview on `longclick` but I'm getting following error .

By the way I'm not getting any error while deleting the last item but when I'm trying to delete any other item after deleting other than last item I'm getting the following error.

Error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
                                                                    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:401)
                                                                    at community.infinity.message.MessageAdapter$1$1$1$1.run(MessageAdapter.java:219)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Code:

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


 Message message = mMessages.get(position);
 holder.setMessage(message.getMessage());

 holder.msgContainer.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
      int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

 if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
 mMessages.remove(position);
 notifyItemRemoved(position);
 notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mMessages.size());
 }

        return false;
    });

 }

}
}
```

Comment: Hello mate, the code which you've provided seems limited to me. But looking at the error log, it seems you are trying to access the index -1 which it out of bounds for array. Maybe share more code or proof read your code again?

Comment: We need the code where you save and restore the selected item index, just before you delete the item itself

Comment: @AntonMakov did you mean the complete code of onBindViewHolder?

Comment: -1 may be a [`NO_POSITION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#NO_POSITION) value.

Comment: @user8027365 yes and also the code where you delete an item

Comment: @AntonMakov sir I've added the code please check it

Answer (score 3):

There's two problems here.

First, there's no need to call `notifyItemRangeChanged()` after you call `notifyItemRemoved()`. The call to `notifyItemRemoved()` will adjust the rest of the data set correctly.

Second, `holder.getAdapterPosition()` will sometimes return `NO_POSITION` (defined as `-1`). This will happen when the view holder knows that it was previously bound to an item that is no longer in the adapter, and hasn't been re-bound yet. Since you just called `notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition())`, the holder's adapter position has been marked as invalid and will now be returned as `-1`.

If you absolutely must call `notifyItemRangeChanged()`, re-write your code as follows:

```
int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
    mMessages.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mMessages.size());
}
```

Comment: Sir, your answer is quite helpful to supress the error but the problem is some items are not deleted at first attempt

Comment: So,is there any way to convert that RecyclerView.NO_POSITION to actual position

Answer (score 0):

Personally I used to have the click listener outside of the adapter(in the fragment/activity) in

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        //I'm saving here the position of the current item
        holder.rootView.setTag(position);

        //you set the listener functionality from the fragment/activity by sending 
        //to the constructor of your adapter
        holder.setLongClickListener(mListener);

        //init other fields of your item
        ...
    }

    // a function that will responsible to update the list without the deleted item
    public void setData(List<Data> data)
    {
         mData = data;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**fragment/activity**

your activity/fragment should implement the interface long click listener

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.LongClickListener
{
   ...

   public boolean onLongClick(View view) 
   {
         int selectedIndex = (int)view.getTag();
         mData.remove(selectedIndex);
         mAdapter.setData(mData);
         return true;
   }
}
```

Don't forget to initialize the adapter with this, it needs your onClickListener implementation.